# Memory leak in Data Access layer using enterprise library

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, memory-leaks, enterprise-library

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class DatabaseService
    {
        Database dal;
        string query;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DbCommand cmd;
        public DateTime GetCurrentDateTime()
        {
            dal = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnStr");
            query = "uspStoreProdure1";
            cmd = dal.GetStoredProcCommand(query);
            return Convert.ToDateTime(dal.ExecuteDataSet(cmd).Tables[0].Rows[0]["CurrentDateTime"]);
        }

        public DateTime GetCurrentDateTime1()
        {
            dal = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnStr");
            query = "uspStoreProdure2";
            cmd = dal.GetStoredProcCommand(query);
            ds = dal.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
           return Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
        }
    // n number of method 
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Missing the real questions, but probably the following :

- DBFactory.CreateDabase value should be disposed at the end.
- Moreover you are keeping the last value alive by keeping the reference within you class. Why are "dal, query, ds and cmd" some fields of the class ? They are different each time you run a query. Declare them locally in methods.
- If you call the DatabaseService twice simultaneously, you will really have some strange behavior...